# Regex Detect Word with consecutive number

Tags: regex, numbers

i need a regular expression that match the following:

- The Word has at least 2 Numbers
- The Numbers are not consecutive

This Word should be ok:

```
abc2def3das
gh2ik7lm2fgd
```

This Word should not be ok:

```
abc20def3asd
abc262def93f34
```

How can i do this with regular expressions?
I have tried something like

```
/[0-9][^0-9][0-9]
```

but this didn't work.

Comment: Is `abc23def4` OK? What program are you using regex with?

Comment: a sentence has multiple words. are you really searching for sentence or in a word only?

Comment: No this Sentence is not ok. Every sentence with 2 consecutive Numbers are not okay. I use Javascript

Comment: how `gh2ik7lm2` is OK that contains more than 2 numbers. Are you looking for at least 2 digits.

Comment: Yes sorry i have edit the question

Comment: is it a sentence or a word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are perhaps looking for that:

```
^\D*\d(?:\D+\d)+\D*$
```

`^` and `$` are anchors for the start and the end of the string.

Comment: There is one problem left it accept words with only 1 number there should be at least 2 numbers in the word

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
^(?=\D*\d\D+\d.*$).+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eA8rP3/5)

*Explanation*:

- `^` - Beginning of string
- `(?=\D*\d\D+\d.*$)` - Positive look-ahead to check if a string has **at least 2** non-consecutive digits (to limit to just 2 digits, replace `.` with `\D`)
- `.+` - any character, 1 or more repetitions
- `$` - End of string